# Kaggle: How to download all files from working directory

Tags: python, download, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, kaggle

I am creating some files in my .ipynb hosted on Kaggle and wonder if there is a way , during the interactive session, to download all file at once or if I have to download them one by one?

[image: Download image data]

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Kaggle's API docs](https://github.com/Kaggle/kaggle-api#retrieve-a-kernels-output) describing how to get a kernel's output.

You're probably looking to use something like this command:

`kaggle kernels output mrisdal/exploring-survival-on-the-titanic -p /path/to/dest`.